# How to sort elements into C++ matrix?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming. I need to sort this matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Mat10 a;
    fillRand(a, 5, 5);
    prnMat(a, 5, 5);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void fillRand(Mat10 m, int n, int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)      
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            m[i][j] = rand() % 1000;    
}

void prnMat(Mat10 a, int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {        
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(8) << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I need to sort the matrix from the beginning from the beginning. The smallest value must be at the beginning of the of the first column. The next must be below it and so on. The result must be sorted matrix - the smallest number must be at the beginning of the left column - the biggest value must be at the end of the matrix. Would you please help to solve the problem?

EDIT

Maybe I found possible solution:

```
void sort(int pin[10][2], int n)
{
    int y,d;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n-1-i; j++)
        {
            if(pin[j+1][1] < pin[j][1])  // swap the elements depending on the second row if the next value is smaller
            {
                y = pin[j][1];
                pin[j][1] = pin[j+1][1];
                pin[j+1][1] = y;
                d = pin[j][0];
                pin[j][0] = pin[j+1][0];
                pin[j+1][0] = d;
            }
            else if(pin[j+1][1] == pin[j][1]) // else if the two elements are equal, sort them depending on the first row
            {
                if(pin[j+1][0] < pin[j][0])
                {
                    y = pin[j][1];
                    pin[j][1] = pin[j+1][1];
                    pin[j+1][1] = y;
                    d = pin[j][0];
                    pin[j][0] = pin[j+1][0];
                    pin[j+1][0] = d;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But since I'm new to programming I don't understand is this the solution?

Comment: You could put the matrix data into a vector, sort it, and then just put the sorted data back in the matrix.

Comment: Is there any example how I can do this?

Comment: Or you could do a sort of 2D bubble sort, I guess. I don't follow, though - are you sorting rows only, or values within the rows? What do you mean 'end of the matrix' - the bottom right square? What progression should the numbers take in order through the matrix?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall post it as an answer. Perhaps, with a little more detail...

Comment: @juanchopanza this is the array. I updated the code.

Comment: If it is a 2D C style array you can just use `std::sort` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//This is the comparation function needed for sort()
bool compareFunction (int i,int j) 
{ 
    return (i<j); 
}

int main()
{
    //let's say you have this matrix
    int matrix[10][10];
    //filling it with random numbers.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 1000;

    //Now we get all the data from the matrix into a vector.
    std::vector<int> vect;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            vect.push_back(matrix[i][j]);

    //and sort the vector using standart sort() function
    std::sort( vect.begin(), vect.end(), compareFunction );

    //Finally, we put the data back into the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = vect.at(i*10 + j);
}
```

After this, the matrix will be sorted by *rows*:

```
1 2
3 4
```

If you want it to be sorted by *cols*:

```
1 3
2 4
```

You need to replace `matrix[i][j]` in the *last cycle only* with `matrix[j][i]`

If you need to read about the the sort() function, you can do it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)
Hope this helps.

Comment: @PeterPenzov you can call `std::sort` directly without copying to the vector. Also, the default comparison sorts from small to large, so you don't actually have to define one (but it is good to know how to do that).

Comment: @juanchopanza, thx, didn't know that std::sort works with non-containers

Answer (score 5):

You can simply call [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on the array:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::sort

int main() {

  int mat[10][10];
  // fill in the matrix
  ...

  // sort it
  std::sort(&mat[0][0], &mat[0][0]+10*10);

}
```