# Sort vector of vectors with doubles according to a column in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I have a matrix consisting of a vector of which each element representing the rows is composed of a vector representing the columns of the matrix. I would like to sort the rows according to the 1st column.

[image]

Each element inside this matrix is a `double`, although the first column contains a number that serves as an identifier (but is not unique).

My goal is to have something like the aggregate functions available in SQL, such as count(*) and sum(*) when I group by the first column.

For instance, if I have:

```
ID       VALUE
1        10
2        20
1        30
2        40
3        60
```

I would like to get:

```
ID       COUNT      MEAN
1        2          20
2        2          30
3        1          60
```

However, I am stuck in the very first step: **how do I sort the rows according to the value of the first element of each row?**

I found a clue [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344559/2210711), and changed adapted the comparator to:

```
bool compareFunction (double i,double j)
{
    return (i<j);
}
```

But the compiler was not very happy about that (making a reference to the stl_algo.h file):

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<double>' to 'double' in argument passing
```

I was therefore wondering if there is a way to sort such a `vector` of `vector`s when it contains `double`s.

Comment: Why do you need to sort as the first step?

Comment: `the first column contains a number that serves as an identifier (but is not unique)`  Maybe you should use `std::multimap<double, std::vector<double>>` instead of a vector of vectors.  If so, then there is no need to sort on the first column since the key (in this case, your first double value) will be sorted automatically.

Comment: You should identify a Primary Key (may be composite) and use that as the sort predicate. Since ID is not unique, maybe it's ID *and* value.

Comment: No need to sort: http://ideone.com/pNf5OD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (imho): use a different datastructure. What you are trying to do is setup a multimap. Oh hey look:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

[stl::multimap - how do i get groups of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247818/stlmultimap-how-do-i-get-groups-of-data)

It'll be faster for large numbers of elements. And is actually a map rather than a vector of vector of double.

Either that, or skip the sorting all together, and count by key using std::map, std::unordered_map, or (if you know the number of keys and/or the keys are offset by 1 with no breaks) std::vector.

To expand, sorting your list to get means will be slow. Sorting (using std::sort) is O(nlogn), and will be O(nlogn) every time you compute this mean. And it is an unessisary step: your stuff is grouped by key reguardless of order. std::map and std::multimap will "sort as you go" which will be just a little faster than sorting every time, but you won't have to sort the whole thing to get the list. Then you can just iterate the multimap to get the mean, O(n) each mean calculation. (It is still O(nlg(n)) to add all the elements to the multimap)

But if you know the key output is going to be 1,2,3...n-1,n, than sorting is a complete waste of time. Just make a counter for each key (since you know what the keys can be) and add to the key while iterating the array.

BUT WAIT THERE IS MORE

If the keys are actually setup the way you are thinking, than the best way from the get go is to forget the table structure, and make build it like this:

```
Index       VALUE
0           10,30
1           20,40
2           60
```

Count is now constant time for each row. Mean for each row is O(n). Getting a list is constant time for each row. EVERYBODY WINS.

Comment: Thank you for coming up with the multimaps. I knew nothing about them and had to learn how to use them from scratch, but now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a comparator function comparing `vector<double>`:

```
struct VecComp {
  bool operator()(const vector<double>& _a, const vector<double>& _b) {
    //compare first elements
  }
}
```

Then you can use `std::sort` on your structure with the new comparator function:

```
std::sort(myMat.begin(), myMat.end(), VecComp());
```

If you are using c++11 features you can also utilize lambda functions here:

```
std::sort(myMat.begin(), myMat.end(), [](const vector<double>& a, const vector<double>& b) {
    //compare the first elements
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own comparator functor to pass into your `vector` declaration:

```
struct comp {
    bool operator() (const std::vector<double>& i, 
                     const std::vector<double>& j) {
        return i[0] < j[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just this?:

```
std::sort(vecOfVecs.begin(), vecOfVecs.end());
```

That should work as `std::vector` has `operator<` which provides lexicographical sorting, which is (a little more specific than) what you want.